# can the length of two xml lists be defined as being required to be equal?

Tags: xml, list, xsd

Assuming you have two lists defined in an xml schema, call them A and B, is there a way to say A must be one or more items and B must be the same length as A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to storing

```
A = (a, a, a)
B = (b, b, b)
```

and enforcing the same length, you could try storing:

```
AB = ([a,b], [a,b], [a,b])
```

This way the constraint you need to enforce would be that each element from AB is of length two and consists of the types A and B - this should be possible in a normal schema.

Answer (score 0):

Co-occurrence constraints are not supported in [XSD 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/). In [XSD 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) which is still in a draft stage, they are. So, sadly, no.